# Npgsql Performance

Tags: ado.net, npgsql

I am trying to implement Npgsql in our DAL and running into issues under heavy load.  the following sample application is a decent representation of just a simple query that under heavy load, throws a 'A command is already in progress' exception.  I am assuming this is due to the lack of MARS support so I also tried creating a connection each time with a using statement around each command only to have the performance become unusable.  I checked that the username is indexed so that shouldn't be an issue.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but I need some advice on how to get this performing well.

OS:  Docker Container: microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk

```
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace npgsqlTest
{
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    { 
        DAL dal = new DAL();

        dal.Prepare();

        var tasks = dal.Users.Select(async user =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(await dal.RunTest(user));
        });
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

public class DAL
{
    private static string _ConnectionString;
    private NpgsqlConnection _Connection;

    public List<string> Users { get; set; } = new List<string>();


    public DAL()
    {
        _ConnectionString = $"Host=192.168.1.1;Username=admin;Port=5432;Password=password;Database=BigDB;";
        _Connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
        _Connection.Open();
    }

    public void Prepare()
    {
        string query = "SELECT username FROM usertable;";

        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, _Connection))
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            using (reader)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Users.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> RunTest(string user)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, Object> { { "username", user } };

        var query = $"SELECT name FROM usertable WHERE username = (@username);";

        var reader = await QueryAsync(query, parameters);

        using (reader)
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var name = reader["name"];

                    if (!(hash is DBNull))
                        return (string)name;
                }
            }
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }

    public async Task<DbDataReader> QueryAsync(string query, Dictionary<string, Object> parameters)
    {
        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, _Connection))
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value == null ? DBNull.Value : parameter.Value);
            }
            cmd.Prepare();
            return await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What you're doing isn't very clear... You seem to have only one database connection (because only one DAL instance) in your entire application and are querying for all users on that connection. For a large number of users using multiple connections in parallel would greatly help. Your usage of `DbCommand.Prepare()` is also wrong: the point is to have a single command prepared only once (you'd do this in your `Prepare()` method, and then reexecute it several times. Your code currently prepares for each invocation, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I changed everything to a connection per command and everything is working as it should.  Thanks!